# The equation $ f'(x)=f(x)$ admits a solution

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, rolles-theorem

> let $f :[0,1]→\mathbb R$ be a fixed continous function such that f is differentiable on (0,1) and $ f(0)=f(1)=0$ .then the equation $ f'(x)=f(x)$ admits
>
> 1. No solution $x\in (0,1)$
> 2. More than one solution $x\in (0,1)$
> 3. Exactly one solution $x\in (0,1)$
> 4. At least one solution $x\in (0,1)$

Actually, mean value theorem doesn't work for $f'(x)$.
The function $f$ has a fixed point and at that point $f'(x)=1$ and at some point $x_0 , f'(x)=0$ (by mean value theorem).but it doesn't get me anywhere! What am I missing?

Obviously 1. Is false since f(x)=0 (also 3.)

2. Is also false since $f(x)=\sin\pi x$

So 4. Is true, but I stuck to prove. Please help.

Comment: $\sin \pi x$ does not satisfy $f'(x) = f(x)$.

Comment: @GEdgar you are right!give me an example of function which has excatly give one solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

$$g(x)=f(x)e^{-x}$$

$$g(0)=g(1)$$

Rolle?

Comment: How do you get that idea of defining function like that... Any easier way?plz help

Comment: From the difference $$f'(x)-f(x)=0$$

Comment: And you think how to make that , also $f'(x)=f(x) $ suggest using e^x ...your answer(hellHound ) is very enlightening

Comment: You mean $e^{-x}$. If we had $$f'(x)+f(x)=0$$ we think $e^x$.

Answer (score 1):

Look at $ g(x)=f(x) \cdot \exp (-x) $. Then $ g $ is also differentiable on $ (0,1) $ with derivative $ g'(x) = (f(x)-f'(x)) \exp (-x) $. Noting that $ g(0) = g(1) = 0 $, Rolle's theorem applies and you get a $ c \in (0,1) $ such that $ g'(c) = 0 $. This implies $ f(c) = f'(c) $.

Comment: Yes I realised and edited it, thank you. It seems like we have posted our answer at almost the same time.

Comment: Also the same answer lol...idk which one to accept